# WebSocket push уведомление

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

Здравствуйте, нужно реализовать WebSocket клиент-сервер, где сервер на .Net и библиотека Fleck, а клиент на JavaScript в браузере.Все работает, но мне необходимо делать периодически уведомления от Сервера к определенным клиентам.Вопрос, как можно идентифицировать клиентов, чтобы Сервер отправлял не всем подключенным клиентом ,а какому то одному(например по id)? Грубо говоря на подобие WhatsApp, Viber -где id является номер телефона пользователя.Как можно жестко привязать клиента при первом коннекте-к какому либо id, и в дальнейшем от сервера отправлять именно этому клиенту.

Comment: на сервере есть "список" всех подключений по ws, по этому списку и происходит рассылка. "Список" может содержать только коннекты ws, Надо организовать новый "список" который будет содержать id/иммя_клиента - ws_коннект. Из этого списка по id и выбирается ws_коннект и по нему идёт отправка. Как это сделать на java я б показал...

Comment: Покажите на Java пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

используется библиотека tomcat для ws, есть страница входа в портал на ней фиксируется логин юзера, он и используется в дальнейшем. есть конфигуратор

```
 public class WsServerConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        sec.getUserProperties().put("username", (String) ((HttpSession) request.getHttpSession()).getAttribute(PARAM_LOGIN));
        sec.getUserProperties().put("sessionID", (String) ((HttpSession) request.getHttpSession()).getId());
        sec.getUserProperties().put("session", (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession());
    }

}
```

и сервер ws

```
  @ServerEndpoint(value = "/WS_server", configurator = WsServerConfigurator.class)
public class WS_server {

    public static Set<Session> ListWsSocet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());


    @OnOpen
    public void OnOpen(EndpointConfig endpointConfig, Session userSession) {
        userSession.getUserProperties().put("username", endpointConfig.getUserProperties().get("username"));
        userSession.getUserProperties().put("sessionID", endpointConfig.getUserProperties().get("sessionID"));
        userSession.getUserProperties().put("session", endpointConfig.getUserProperties().get("session"));
        ListWsSocet.add(userSession);
    }
```

есть метод для передачи сообщения выбранному юзеру

```
  public void SendMessage(String username, String message) {
        ListWsSocet.stream().forEach((Session x) -> {

            if (x.getUserProperties().containsValue(username)) {
                try {
                    x.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
                    return;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

у меня довольно хитрая обработка входных сообщений от клиентов :) (это отдельная тема) .
На onMessage вызывается метод по обработки данных,  в котором можно вызвать SendMessage с соответствующими параметрами

```
 @OnMessage
    public void OnMessage(String data, Session userSession) {
// пропущено ....
   try {
            cl = Class.forName(Singleton.ListCommand.get(command_).getClass().getName());
            method = cl.getMethod(command_, java.lang.String.class, Session.class);
            method.invoke(Singleton.ListCommand.get(command_), data_, userSession);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```