# Внутренний не статический класс. Верный подход? WebSocket

Tags: java, классы, websocket

Подскажите правильность такого решения.

У меня есть точка подключения вебсокета на Java (сервер). В нем реализованы методы `onOpen`, `onMessage`, `onClose` и `onError`.

Речь пойдет о методе `onMessage`.

Мне не хочется набивать этот метод свичем который будет огромным для всех сообщений которые возможны.

Я сделал такую вот штуку (использовал внутренний не статический класс для обработки сообщений)

```
    @ServerEndpoint(value = "/endpoint", configurator = SocketConfigurator.class, encoders=WsEncoder.class, decoders=WsDecoder.class)
public class WsEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WsEndpoint.class);

    private static final CopyOnWriteArrayList<WsUser> wsWebUsers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<WsUser>();

    public WsEndpoint() {
        LOGGER.info("ENDPOINT CREATED");
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        LOGGER.info("ENDPOINT ONOPEN");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, WsMessage wsMessage) {

        new WsOnMessage(session, wsMessage);

    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {

    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable ex) {
        LOGGER.error("ENDPOINT ERROR", ex);
    }

    private class WsOnMessage {

        private Session session;
        private WsMessage wsMessage;

        public WsOnMessage(Session session, WsMessage wsMessage) {
            this.session = session;
            this.wsMessage = wsMessage;

            call();

        }

        private void call() {
            switch (wsMessage.getType()) {
                ...
            }
        }

    }

}
```

верно ли так делать? Может есть более элегантный способ обработки сообщений?

Спасибо.

Comment: а чего вы таким образом хотели добиться? читабельности? но вместо свича в onMessage() тот же свич в WsOnMessage.call(). Если  хотели уменьшить количество линий в файле, то выносить тогда надо не во внутренний класс. Если событий реально много и их обработчики громоздки, можно подумать над применением шаблона "Command Pattern"

Comment: @Tsyklop вот тут пример с использование рефлексии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774723/websocket-push-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/775346#775346  
для этого структура сообщения должна быть вида команда+разделитель+данные, где команда = метод по обработке данных

Comment: @Tsyklop  для этого нет необходимости набивать свичи или ифы.все методы можно поместить в один или несколько классов разместить их в определённой папке. и  при запуске приложения просканировать эти классы и извлечь из них методы поместив в хашмап имя_метода:"полный путь до метода". такой вариант работает стабильно уже в нескольких проектах. есть страница (формируемая с помощью jsp) класс с методами обработки. пишется/правится только конкретный класс к данной странице и всё. методы добавляются/удаляются и не надо заботиться о том, что ещё гдето надо прописать/удалить/изменить имя

Comment: @Вадим пример можно?

Comment: @Tsyklop без проблем.. как? teamViewer?

Comment: @Вадим можно и его. Скайп alucid2.