# Клиент Websocket. Соединение и отправка данных

Tags: java, json, websocket

Есть пример подключения к сокету на javascript.

```
 self.ws = new WebSocket((window.location.protocol == "http:" ? "ws://" : "wss://") + window.location.host + "/api/get");
    self.ws.onopen = function () {

        if (self.__ws_task)
            clearInterval(self.__ws_task);
        self.ws.send(
            JSON.stringify({
                command: "subscribe",
                data: 'test1:test2',
                data2: '{temp:[32, 31, 41, 51, 55, 54, 61, 91], temp2:[1018433255,805863782,-3330707801]}'
            })
        );
    };
```

Как сделать тоже самое в Java? **И потом еще получать ПОСТОЯННО сообщения в ответ?**

Пробовал так:

```
   final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("ws://temp.com/api/get"));

    clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(new WebsocketClientEndpoint.MessageHandler() {
        public void handleMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("message");
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    });
```

**WebsocketClientEndpoint.java**

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import javax.websocket.*;
import java.net.URI;


@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

Session userSession = null;
private MessageHandler messageHandler;

public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
    try {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Connection open events.
 *
 * @param userSession the userSession which is opened.
 */
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
    System.out.println("opening websocket");
    this.userSession = userSession;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("command", "subscribe");
        obj.put("data", "test1:test2");
        obj.put("data2", "{temp:[32, 31, 41, 51, 55, 54, 61, 91], temp2:[1018433255,805863782,-3330707801]}");
        String message = obj.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String message = obj.toString();
    System.out.println(message);
    this.sendMessage(message);
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Connection close events.
 *
 * @param userSession the userSession which is getting closed.
 * @param reason the reason for connection close
 */
@OnClose
public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
    System.out.println("closing websocket");
    this.userSession = null;
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Message Events. This method will be invoked when a client send a message.
 *
 * @param message The text message
 */
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message) {
    if (this.messageHandler != null) {
        this.messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
    }
}

/**
 * register message handler
 *
 * @param msgHandler
 */
public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
    this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
}

/**
 * Send a message.
 *
 * @param message
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("send message");
    this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
}

/**
 * Message handler.
 *
 * @author Jiji_Sasidharan
 */
public static interface MessageHandler {

    public void handleMessage(String message);
}
}
```

Получаю такой результат:

```
opening websocket
{"command":"subscribe","data":"test1:test2","data2":"{temp:[32, 31, 41, 51, 55, 54, 61, 91], temp2:[1018433255,805863782,-3330707801]}"}
send message
```

Всем заранее спасибо за любой совет!

Comment: Получать сообщения надо на стороне JS или Java?

Comment: Получать сообщения надо на стороне JAVA

Comment: Попробую помочь вам после работы

Comment: @jessez https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774723/websocket-push-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/775346#775346 пример